# How do I use aws cognito list_users function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to run cognito's list_users command and use all the general settings, but I get the below error. What am I doing incorrectly?

````
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId=os.environ['userpool_id'],
        AttributesToGet=[],
        Limit=20,
        # PaginationToken='string',
        Filter=''
    )
    return response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable",
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response has to be in JSON format. The json.dumps method accepts an optional parameter called default which is expected to be a function. Every time JSON tries to convert a value it does not know how to convert it will call the function passed to it. The function will receive the object in question, and it is expected to return the JSON representation of the object. Here, a string representation of the value is returned.

Refer updated code below:

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime

def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId='us-east-1_ChpG3EsuS',
        AttributesToGet=[],
        Limit=20,
        # PaginationToken='string',
        Filter=''
    )
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response, default = myconverter)
    }
```